# Scala: best way to handle exceptions from Java library?

Tags: scala, exception, scala-java-interop

Let's say I'm using a Java library from my Scala project. That Java library throws exceptions all over the place, but I don't feel comfortable just letting them propagate "in the Scala world", since there's no way to be sure what exceptions a Scala method can throw (except by documenting them). So this is the kind of code I tend to write:

```
def doesNotThrowExceptions(parameter: String): Either[Throwable, T] =
  catching(classOf[IOException], classOf[NoSuchAlgorithmException]) either {
    // Code calling the Java library
    // Code generating a value of type T
  }
```

Then, typically, I'll use `Either.RightProjection.flatMap` to chain methods that return `Either[Throwable, ...]` or `Either.RightProjection.map` to mix methods that return `Either[Throwable, ...]` and other methods. Or simply `Either.fold` to do something with the `Throwable` value. Somehow, though, this still doesn't feel totally *right*.

Is this the most "idiomatic" way to deal with Java's exceptions in Scala? Isn't there a better way?

Comment: You know you can use for-comprehensions instead of flatMap and map? Makes the code look much nicer.

Comment: @ziggystar: Yes, but the map/flatMap vs for debate is almost a religious matter. :) I'd say using for can really make the code easier to read, but if you chain only a couple of map/flatMap, _not_ using for can make the code clearer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a *single* most idiomatic way to deal with Java's exceptions because there are at least four different cases they'll get thrown:

1. Something that neither you nor the library designer really expected to go wrong went wrong.
2. Something that the library designer hoped would work didn't, and you need to know the details.
3. Something you hoped would work didn't, and you don't need to know the details.
4. Sometimes the method produces a value and sometimes not, and it communicates that by throwing an exception.

Best practices arguably differ for each of these cases

#### 1. Truly exceptional exceptions

Scala has fully-featured exception handling.  There is nothing wrong with letting an unanticipated exception propagate uncaught until you're at a level where you can do something about it.  Packaging every possible exception into an `Either` can waste a lot of time.  Just document what you know you're not handling, and use try/catch at an appropriately high level (e.g. a `saveEverything` method should probably go in a try/catch block (or wrap its contents in one) because no matter what went wrong, if saving everything failed you probably want to attempt to salvage the situation, not just die).

In particular, you probably want to handle `Error` this way and only package `Exception`, not all `Throwable`s, into `Either`.

#### 2. Exceptions that you need to know about

This is the case you're talking about, and you've already given several good suggestions for how to deal with them.  As you've already noticed, you can use `catching` to package the exceptions into `Either`.  You then can also

a. Use pattern matching, which will let you pull apart your `Either` in more depth:

```
doesNotThrowExceptions("par").right.map(transformData) match {
  case Left(ioe: IOException) => /* ... */
  case Left(nsae: NoSuchAlgorithmException) => /* ... */
  case Right(x) => /* ... */
  case Left(e) => throw e  // Didn't expect this one...
}
```

b. Downconvert to `Option` after logging the error:

```
doesNotThrowExceptions("par").left.map{ e =>
  println("You're not going to like this, but something bad happened:")
  println(e)
  println("Let's see if we can still make this work....")
}.right.toOption
```

c. If exceptions are a really important part of your flow-control, `Either` may not be enough.  You might instead want to define your own `Either`-like class with more than just `Left` and `Right`.  Or you can nest the left side of the `Either`:

```
try { Right(/* java code */) }
catch {
  case ioe: IOException => Left(Left(ioe))
  case nsae: NoSuchAlgorithmException => Left(Right(nsae))
}
```

d. Use Scalaz `Validation`, which is a lot like `Either` but is tailored a little more to exception handling.

#### 3. Exceptions where you only need to know something went wrong, and

#### 4. Exceptions thrown to indicate no-return-value

Even though these are conceptually two different categories, you handle them the same way:

```
catching(classOf[IOException], classOf[NoSuchAlgorithmException]) opt { ... }
```

to get an `Option` back.  Then `map`, `flatMap`, etc..

Answer (score 6):

I always prefer `scalaz.Validation` over `scala.Either`. The two are algebraically identical structures, but the former is functionally richer (has more useful methods and type class instances).

Check [this link](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/scala/practical-scalaz-2518) for a great presentation by Chris Marshall on `scalaz.Validation` and other Scalaz goodies.

In order to talk to the code that uses classic exception handling mechanism, I have defined the following enriching methods and a type class instance:

```
implicit def catchW[A](underlying: Catch[A]) = new CatchW(underlying)

class CatchW[A](underlying: Catch[A]) {
  def validation(body: => A): Validation[Throwable, A] = {
    underlying.withApply(_.fail)(body.success)
  }

  def vnel(body: => A): ValidationNEL[Throwable, A] = {
    underlying.withApply(_.failNel)(body.success)
  }
}

implicit def catchMonoid[A] = new Monoid[Catch[A]] {
  val zero = noCatch
  def append(x: Catch[A], y: => Catch[A]) = x or y
}
```

Comment: Validation.fromTryCatch() is in v7, making it even nicer.

Comment: We've been discussing using Scalaz in our project for a while, now. We'll probably start with scalaz.Validation. I think we really need it.

Comment: There's a throws method on Function0W in Scalaz6 defined as `try {success(f())} catch {case e => failure(e)}`, which looks to be the same thing as `fromTryCatch`.